# how important is it that libraries treat utf16xx and utf32xx as equal peers to utf8?

Tags: unicode, interop

does any signifigant interchange take place in formats other than ascii/utf8? are there any fields where utf16xx and utf32xx are used heavily? i ask as a writer of multiple libraries that work on unicode text, and the burden of supporting all five major variants is quite high compared to the perceived utility.

Comment: UTF-16 is Unicode on Windows. They didn't use UTF-8 because it hadn't been invented at the time Windows went Unicode!! UTF-32 is pretty rarely used.

Comment: @David: you do, however, have to decode UTF-8/16 to UTF-32 when processing characters in order to handle codepoints correctly, even if you do the decoding on a per-codepoint basis and not a per-string basis.

Comment: C libraries, I assume?  For what purpose, and on what platform?

Comment: What exactly does the interchange consist in? ABIs? Binary files? Markup languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to interchange, I guess you are right that UTF-8 is prevalent. Some cases of using UTF-16 are various binary protocols such as DCOM, Java RMI and (maybe???) CORBA.

As for UTF-32 I've never heard of a case where it is used for interchange.

Answer (score 2):

Windows and Java both treat Unicode as UTF-16 internally, and Python uses UTF-16 or UTF-32 depending on the platform.  So more than just UTF-8 is important for these.  These are just the cases I'm most familiar with, I'm sure there are others.

So, in my opinion, if you have a Unicode library, you should support UTF-16 and UTF-32.  (I can't believe UTF-32 is too difficult, since there's no special processing involved besides byte ordering.  Although, I'm not a Unicode library author :) )

Comment: i know utf16 and utf32 are used extensively internally, but i'm interested mostly in interop. do any signifigant tools/platforms produce utf16xx and utf32xx for interchange?

Comment: utf16 on windows. I've never encountered utf32 in the wild.

Comment: Like David Heffernan said, if you're working with the Windows API, you need to be able to work with UTF-16.  For interchange, you often have the option to save things in UTF-16, but I've never used it--for European alphabets it doesn't have an advantage.  However, it may be advantageous for Asian languages.

Answer (score 1):

One important point is XML: it can come in pretty much any encoding imaginable, but UTF-8 is by far the most common.

**However**, the [XML spec says this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#characters):

> All XML processors must accept the UTF-8 and UTF-16 encodings of Unicode

So if your application/library handles XML in any way it must support UTF-16 *at least* in that portion. Note that a conforming parser that converts the data to UTF-8 for processing would be enough here.